# java : Extend Applet process timeout

Tags: java, applet

While running a java Applet in browser, a process `java.exe` starts and a java console appears if enabled. As long as the process is alive, the console is visible indicating the same.

This process doesn't exit if I to other page or even close the browser. It terminates automatically after some random time. Is there a way to control that time duration?

I've a functionality that starts with an applet , then navigate to some other page for completion. To use it again I return to applet page and here the applet initializes again if the process is already terminated which takes some time. I'd like to extend this time if possible so that applet doesn't initialize again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to control that time duration?

No.  (Unless you wrote the browser.)

But your question indicates you have the entire wrong view of what an applet is and should be.  That question indicates you think the applet/JVM should be 'in command' of the web pages/browser, whereas it is really just a guest in the web page.  The browser/page controls the applet/JVM, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm aware that browser calls the init, start, stop, destroy methods and applet's whole life cycle is determined by browser. The destroy is called as soon as I navigate to other page but the process java.exe lives after destroy has been invoked. I'm interested in what happens behind the scene and if there is a way to exploit it. 
But your first part answers that I can't even though its disappointing.